# analyzing time complexity of a recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I'm learning how to calculate time complexity of an algorithm. I am able to calculate time complexity of a simple algorithm that includes loops , but I'm having trouble calculating time  complexity of algorithms that uses recursion. I need help in determining time complexity of recursive algorithm.

The problem statement is as follows:

**Given two strings S and T, return if they are equal when both are typed into empty text editors. # means a backspace character.**

Example 1:

> Input: S = "ab#c", T = "ad#c" Output: true Explanation: Both S and T
>   become "ac".

Example 2:

> Input: S = "ab##", T = "c#d#" Output: true Explanation: Both S and T
>   become "".

Example 3:

> Input: S = "a##c", T = "#a#c" Output: true Explanation: Both S and T
>   become "c".

And the algorithm I have developed is as follows :

```
 public boolean backspaceCompare(String S, String T) {
      return removeAndDelete(S).equals(removeAndDelete(T));
    }


public  String removeAndDelete(String input){
    int index = input.indexOf('#');
    if(index==-1)
        return input;
    else if(index == 0)
        return removeAndDelete(input.substring(index+1));
    else
        return removeAndDelete(input.substring(0,index-1)+input.substring(index+1));
}
```

Now I would like to calculate time complexity of my algorithm. Please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity is quadratic. Let `N` be the length of the input string. The number of recursive calls is equal to the number of `#` characters in the input, which is `O(N)`. Each time you make a recursive call the substring operations take `O(N)`, so we have an upper bound of `O(N^2)`. With an input like `aaaa####` it's easy to see that the complexity is at least `O(N^2)`,

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. Now I understand